# EF Core SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'MenuCategories' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying to save some data into my MenuItems table but I'm prevented by the error

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'MenuCategories' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

I am just trying to set the foreign key using the category id I have, I am not quite sure why I am getting the above error.

This is my `MenuItem` model:

```
public class MenuItemViewModel
{
    [Key]
    [Column("MenuItem_Id")]
    public int MenuItemId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("MenuCategory_Id")]
    public MenuCategoryViewModel MenuCategory { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `MenuCategory` model:

```
public class MenuCategoryViewModel
{
    [Key]
    [Column("MenuCategory_Id")]
    public int MenuCategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to assign it the id of an existing category, I do not want it to create a new category.

Comment: Hint: the error above indicates that the Id that you are inserting to is an _identity_ column, meaning you have to give the database server control on how it populates the `MenuItemId` unless you set `Identity_Insert` to off. I am not an expert on _Entity Framework Core_, but have you tried to pass the object without the `MenuItemId` populated? Why do you need to populate the `MenuItemId` yourself?

Comment: @KristianneNerona I am trying to populate it my self because I want to use an existing category I do not want it to create a new one.

Comment: Can you confirm whether MenuCategoryId is defined as an IDENTITY column in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to assume that your `DbContext` class is like this:

```
public class Context: DbContext
{
    public Context(DbContextOptions<MenuContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<MenuCategory> MenuCategories{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
}
```

So your controller can be coded this way:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(MenuItemViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var menuItem = new MenuItem 
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            ...
        };

        var menuCategory = _Context.MenuCategories.Find(model.MenuCategory.MenuCategoryId);
        menuItem.MenuCategory = menuCategory;
        _Context.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
        await _Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new { id = menuItem.MenuCategory.MenuCategoryId });
    }
    return View(menuItem);
}
```

From what I can tell, you are assuming that if you tell your View that your `MenuCategory` has a selected id, your view will populate the `MenuCategory`. It does not work that way. The view does not have a way of knowing what your `MenuCategory` is. You need to populate the values with your `DbContext`, which happens in your *controller*.

Also, it would be best if you separate your *entities* from your *view models*. It is so much easier if your classes have their own simple responsibility: your entities will represent a logical record in your database, and your view model will represent the data that comes from and goes to your controllers.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comments of you wanting to use an existing Id to not add a new category, then what you are doing for your save is a little wrong `_Context.Add(menuItem);` will cause a database `INSERT` to fire - this is because the `.Add()` marks all of the entities as new entities to be saved to the context, yet you arent wanting that - what you should do is something along the lines of Add the `menuItem` - Query the Database to get the `MenuCategory` that you want to have attached to it - and then set that on the `menuItem` and then save.

Comment: Oh okay, this fixed my issue.  So whenever I need to use an existing id for my foreign key I must first get the object of it from the database then assign it then save it?

Comment: Generally yes, this is because you want the SQL statement generated to be an Update which will trigger through 'Change Tracking' of the existing entity

Comment: What if I'm already getting it through a .Include() while loading? Doesn't that count as loading the object? I'm doing this, and still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this error if you've 'implicitly' added an entity to the database, saved it and then try to manually add it.

Clearly the following is HORRIBLE code and would make no sense to write this. However it's possible to do this accidentally with a more complicated situation.

```
var category = new MenuCategoryViewModel() { ... };

// assign category to menu item    
var model = new MenuItemViewModel() 
            {
                MenuCategory = category 
            };  

db.Add(model);
db.SaveChanges();

// 'category' object has an ID because we saved it
// even though it was never explicitly added to the context

// add the category to the context 
db.Add(category);
db.SaveChanges();  // fails with IDENTITY error
```

If you are adding an entity without explicitly adding it to the context you mustn't add it later after it already has been assigned a key.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this exception was thrown because the software had an entity with auto generated ID and I tried to insert a new record in database with an id generated by my code. The solution was clear and simple: remove the ID set in my code.